# Exclude formatting

Tags: reactjs, jsx, formatter

Is there a way to exclude next node/line in Javascript/react from formatting with native visual studio code formatter like it is possible with Prettier extension?

With Prettier, this comment ignores next node:

```
// prettier-ignore
```

I would like this line to be ignored from formatting (property in object definition), it is JSX file

```
    icon: <svg enable-background="new 0 0 218.207 218.207" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 218.2 163.7" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m214.3 0h-210.4c-2.154 0-3.897 1.743-3.897 3.896v155.9c0 2.154 1.743 3.897 3.897 3.897h210.4c2.154 0 3.897-1.743 3.897-3.897v-155.9c0-2.153-1.743-3.896-3.897-3.896zm-206.5 35.07h35.07v70.14h-35.07zm202.6 70.14h-11.69v-70.14h11.69zm0-77.93h-15.59c-2.154 0-3.897 1.743-3.897 3.897v77.93c0 2.154 1.743 3.897 3.897 3.897h15.59v42.86h-202.6v-42.86h38.97c2.154 0 3.897-1.743 3.897-3.897v-77.93c0-2.154-1.743-3.897-3.897-3.897h-38.97v-19.48h202.6z"/><circle cx="113" cy="136.4" r="7.793"/><path d="m66.24 113h109.1c2.154 0 3.897-1.743 3.897-3.897v-77.93c0-2.153-1.743-3.896-3.896-3.896h-109.1c-2.154 0-3.897 1.743-3.897 3.897v77.93c0 2.154 1.743 3.897 3.897 3.897zm3.897-77.93h101.3v70.14h-101.3z"/><rect x="66.24" y="132.5" width="11.69" height="7.793"/><rect x="85.72" y="132.5" width="11.69" height="7.793"/><rect x="128.6" y="132.5" width="11.69" height="7.793"/><rect x="148.1" y="132.5" width="11.69" height="7.793"/></svg>,
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that default VS Code javascript formatter does not format SVG if file is saved as JSX. If it is saved as JS it formats it. However, it would be still interesting to know if there is an option to exclude something from formatting, like with Prettier.